# Has anyone seen power cycle corruption in industrial SD cards?

Tags: power-supply, linux, sd

I am using a micro SD card in a new embedded Linux system (choice of SD was not mine, was made by the hardware guys).  I have seen a problem before where power cycling of a system without doing a proper shutdown has resulted in the SD card being unusable - yes even reformatting it didn't revive it.

I was wondering if anyone has seen this type of failure in industrial rated SD cards, as they're apparently designed to handle sudden power failure better.

Comment: Tangentially relvant on SD card construction and hidden counterfeits: http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?p=918

Comment: Sadly I have only heard of it resulting in corruption, sorry.

Comment: Thanks pcj, I had read bunnie's article before, extremely informative.  I'm working on a new Linux design where SD is the main storage, I am quite worried that we'll start seeing these SD cards start dying after 6 months and we'll be in big trouble - there seems to be lots of data out there on the net about the cheaper MLC cards dying after a while.  I am not sure whether the industrial cards would make much of a difference, they claim to but it's all pretty hand wavy without too many specifics.

Comment: We have massive SD-card problems with one of our designs (embedded linux). We already switched to industrial SD-cards, which seems to have somewhat improved the situation, but we still experience data corruption data or even total failures. I was just doing some research about that topic and stumbled over this post.

Comment: @Rev1.0 I know you posted this awhile ago but I also was recently in a situation where we had massive SD failures in an embedded Linux system (I also stumbled across this post doing some final research). We solved the problem, and the system is robust even with consumer grade or low quality cards. If you're still researching that let me know, I can share what we did. Interested to hear your solutions too.

Comment: @JasonC: Thanks for the feedback, I would be interested to hear about what your problem was and how you fixed it. We are still investigating the issue. You can contact me per E-Mail if you like "freese AT cynox DOT de". I will remove this comment to prevent mail spam as soon as you replied.

Comment: I'll drop you an email tonight. I've got your address written down, you can remove.

Comment: @JasonC Can you post your findings as an answer here?

Answer (score 2):

We had this on microSD cards used on the OLPC XO-1.5; an internally mounted rarely removed card; the card would become unusable and unresponsive.  Our failure analysis was very extensive.  We worked directly with the vendor.  We solved it by leaving power to the card for a few seconds after host power down.  We also added a discharge switch to avoid a slow fall.

We were otherwise controlling all other relevant specifications of the card in the relationship with the vendor, and I don't recall any mention of "industrial" or "consumer" rating, but one of our design goals was low cost, so I'll guess "consumer".  Perhaps "industrial" was a matter of binning.  We did require five or six years endurance though, to ensure product life.

Comment: Mr. Cameron, I am investigating simular problems. Is it possible to get in contact with you and discuss the electrical circuit that you have used as solution?
We have problems with e.g. leak current trough the sd card DAT lines. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: For discharge clamps, we use 2N7002 with series 22 Ω resistor.  Gate is driven by inverted power signal.  Leakage through bus?  Include the SDIO bus pullups in the same power domain, and do not pull them up in the CPU, unless you also add code to switch them off.  Schematics are on our Wiki.  <quozl@laptop.org>

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the problem is still actual for you Fred?

The problems you describe are quite similar to the problems we encounter. Also the fact that some cards become completely unusable is something we have seen. We have seen that the cards even become corrupt or unusable *without* a power cycle after about 1 to 4 weeks.

We found entries in the linux system log(kern.log / dmesg) similar to this:

```
mmcblk0: retrying using single block read
```

or this?

```
mmcblk0: error -110 sending status command, retrying
...
```

As the problem can come from a lot of different causes, the following list may help you find and solve the problem.

- Power supply MUST be stable, check if regulator/smps is stable.
- Very close to the SD card capacitors(about 47uF) must be placed with low ESR.
- Flash can be written limited times, so limit writes as much as possible in software. Reads are no problem.
- (not tested by me) The SD card should stay powered for a few extra milliseconds longer than the processor after removing system power. This way the SD card can finish it's job. (can be created with a larger capacitor and a diode at the SD card's power supply)

another suggestion is to investigate FAT optimisations in the SD card controller which may cause corruption or make the card unusable (see the [linaro SD card survey](https://wiki.linaro.org/WorkingGroups/KernelArchived/Projects/FlashCardSurvey))